# set background to div with 16% opacity

Tags: html, css

so i want to add a background with an opacity of 16% that actually works [what it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2o45.png)
[what i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le0lc.png)

current code:

```css
#main-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  text-align: center;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 65%, 50% 100%, 0 65%, 0 0) !important;
  /*background-color: rgba(37, 170, 231, 0.904);*/
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

```html
<div id="main-top">
  <div id="sosa">
    <h2>Birds</h2>

  </div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. In your css there is no background image, in the HTML there is no image. So start by giving the relevant css/html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```css
#main-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 4em;

  text-align: center;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 65%, 50% 100%, 0 65%, 0 0) !important;
  /*background-color: rgba(37, 170, 231, 0.904);*/
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
}

#main-top::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    background: url(https://placekitten.com/640/560) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.4;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-top">
    <div id="sosa">
      <h2>Birds</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: would have been easier not to create a pseudo-element. Simply use `background` property to add the image and a background-color in rgba in one value. Alternativly apply a filter to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use opacity in CSS

```
.transparent_class {
 opacity: 0.16;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-top {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
   padding-bottom: 4em;
   text-align: center;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 65%, 50% 100%, 0 65%, 0 0) !important;
  /*background-color: rgba(37, 170, 231, 0.904);*/
   background-color: var(--primary-color);
   opacity: 0.1 !important;
   }
```